# Was there a cinema-only scene in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, alternate-version, the-force-awakens

I believe to clearly remember an impressive shot from Star Wars: The Force Awakens of stormtroopers emerging from landing ships on Takodana, while already firing at Maz Kanata's castle. I did not find this scene when I watched the movie on DVD. Does anyone else remember it? Could it be that this scene was cut out for the home media version?

Answer (score 4):

Having seen the movie both in the theater and on Blu-ray multiple times each, I do not recall any difference in the scenes between the two movies (I could be wrong, I am not infallible). However, it is possible you are conflating the scene you remember with another one.

I went ahead and rewatched that portion of the movie on the Blu-ray edition, and took some screen shots showing the sequence of events.

First, the tie fighters fly in.

[image]

---

Next, the tie fighters attack Maz Kanata's castle. These are blaster strikes from the air, not by stormtroopers.

[image]

---

Next,  <strike>young Alan Rickman's</strike> Kylo Ren's shuttle lands. Notice that stormtroopers are already on the ground, and there is no shot showing them arrive. Nor do previous scenes show any troop transport ships.

[image]

---

Near the end, a rebel shuttle carrying Leia and some other personnel lands. By this point the stormtroopers and tie fighters have already left.

[image]

You *may* be conflating the rebel forces landing and the ship opening with the stormtroopers landing.

---

You may also be conflating the scene you imagine with this one very near the start of the film. Stormtroopers rush out of multiple troop transports onto Jakku, while under fire from locals.

[image]

Comment: No, obviously they are confusing *insert random scene* with *second random scene*. Most likely they are confusing the intro scene with the storm troopers attacking jakku.

Answer (score 1):

There is no recorded evidence of scene changes between the Cinematic and Home Video releases. The Blu Ray has some deleted scenes but no extended or modified cut.